# Hosting two different servers with one domain

Tags: server, dns, ports

I'm trying to host web pages using Win Server 2016. Currently, I have Jira and my personal web (IIS) servers. Using AWS, I currently have "myec2.com:port1" and "myec2.com/port2" running fine. And I'm planning to buy a domain "myname.com" to be connected to "myec2.long.name.com"

What I hope to do is "myname.com/jira" and "myname.com/mypage" or "jira.myname.com" and "mypage.myname.com" can redirect to Jira server and the IIS server. Is there a way I can achieve this goal?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you buy a domain like **myname.com** you will be able to configure any number of sub-domains such as **jira.myname.com** or **mypage.myname.com** as you like.

Usually what you would do is point those sub-domains to your server's IP then handle requests to those domains by setting up a web server (like apache or nginx) and configuring a virtual host (apache) or a server block (nginx) for each one of those sub-domains.